# How i can Skin the message box of my app when the vcl styles are activated?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, vcl-styles

I'm using the Application.MessageBox to show messages on my VCL application, but when the application had a vcl style applied the message window is shown with the windows style instead of the current vcl style.

Sample code

```
 Application.MessageBox('Hello World', 'Hello', MB_OK + MB_ICONINFORMATION);
```

Sample Image

[image]

How I can show a message box with the current vcl style?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Application.MessageBox function internally call the [MessageBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WinAPi function, that window is not a form created by delphi so can't be skinned with the Vcl styles. Instead you must use one of the dialogs classes and functions declarated in the Vcl.Dialogs unit like the `MessageDlg` function.

```
MessageDlg('Hello World',  mtInformation, [mbOK], 0);
```

[image]

Comment: Do these dialog classes support CTRL+C yet?

Comment: I just tried. Doesn't support CTRL+C very well because when you press the keys, the computer beeps the warning bell. I guess I'll debug it and QC it.

Comment: Hmm, the `Beep` is intentional and explicitly written into the CTRL+C handler. Bizarre that they would intentionally vary from the platform standard.